# Providing folder permission and accessing it from another server IIS

Tags: c#, iis, folder-access

I have two servers Server A and Server B. I have an application running in Server A. I'm trying to access contents from a folder in Server B and from the application running in Server A.

The Server A application is running from IIS and I'm using the below piece of code in C# to read the folder contents.

```
public static string getFileInfo()
{
    string retval = string.Empty;
    DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\atom\bala");
    FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.bak");
    string str = "";
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        str = str + ", " + file.Name;
    }
    return str;
}
```

In the above code atom is my "Server B" and "bala" is the folder. I can clearly understand that my application from Server A is not having access to this folder. So i'm getting the below error message:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\atom\bala' is denied.
```

I don't know how to get this access sorted. I have tried the following things:

- Provided access to NETWORK SERVICE.
- Anonymous Authentication is enabled in IIS.

Apologies if my question is very basic as I'm a noob programmer. Can someone please help me sort this?

Answer (score 0):

you add permission folder "bala" share to user "everyone"
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nPcY.png)

Comment: If I can give access to everyone I would have not asked this question at all.

Comment: you can try this: on server A use api convert file to base64, server B use api